# PDE with homogeneous boundary conditions in 3D

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I'm thinking I need to use Fourier transform but I'm not sure. All I pretty much know Is how to use variable separation but I doubt that will help me with this problem.
$$
u_{tt}+au_{t}-c^2(u_{xx}+u_{yy}+u_{zz})=0
$$
$$
x,y,z\in(0,\pi)
$$
$$
u(0,y,z,t)=u(\pi,y,z,t)=0
$$
$$
u(x,0,z,t)=u(x,\pi,z,t)=0
$$
$$
u(x,y,0,t)=u(x,y,\pi,t)=0
$$
$$
u(x,y,z,0)=0
$$
$$
u_{t}(x,y,z,0)=sin(x)sin(y)sin^2(z)
$$

Comment: Separation of variables will work I think, but will be loooong.